# Proving using a SAT solver that KB entails D

Tags: logic, proof-techniques, sat-solvers

Suppose you're given this KB:

$$KB = (A, A ⇒ B, A ⇒ C, B ∧ C ⇒ D)$$

How would you show using a SAT solver that $KB \vDash D$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Use the SAT solver to search for a counterexample.

To check that $KB \models \varphi$, you need to know whether there is any assignment that is consistent with $KB$ but that does not satisfy $\varphi$.  In other words, you need to know whether $KB \land \neg \varphi$ is satisfiable or not.  If $KB \land \neg \varphi$ is satisfiable, then you have found a counterexample that demonstrates that $KB \not\models \varphi$.  If $KB \land \neg \varphi$ is not satisfiable, then you proven that $KB \models \varphi$ is true.

Now apply that to your specific example.